# readxl or tidyxl: Prevent date coersion when reading from Excel xlsx

Tags: r, readxl

Is there any way to prevent coercion of dates when reading data from Excel?  I'm using either the `readxl` package or the `tidyxl` package. The `tidyxl` package is terrific, but it automatically moves the data into the `date` column.

Also, I was intrigued by this sentence from the Help page for the `xlsx_cells()` function:  " *xlsx_cells() attempts to infer the correct data type of each cell, returning its value in the appropriate column (error, logical, numeric, date, character). In case this cleverness is unhelpful, the unparsed value and type information is available in the 'content' and 'type' columns.*"   It's this *unparsed value* that I'm looking for.

Alternatively, I'm looking for something similar to [TextReader](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textreadr/readme/README.html), except for XLSX files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This has just been fixed in tidyxl as of https://github.com/nacnudus/tidyxl/pull/80.  Sorry that I didn't notice this post two years ago!